# Why Object.assign({}, ...) with an empty object literal when other objects are also passed in?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading an introduction to Redux reducers (https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles) which contains the following example of a reducer:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case 'COMPLETE_TODO':
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: true
          })
        }
        return todo
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

It seems from its documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) that `Object.assign()` will 'merge together' all the objects passed into it. In this case, however, `todo` and `{completed: true}` are already objects, so I don't see the point of passing an empty object literal, `{}`, as the first argument to `Object.assign()`. Can anybody clarify this?

Comment: Having absolutely no knowledge of Redux, I assume it's to avoid mutating the original objects and to return a *new* object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `Object.assign`, the first object you give it will have all the rest of the objects merged into it. That is to say, the first object will be mutated.

If you want to avoid mutating the objects you're merging, it's helpful to pass in the empty object as the first parameter to prevent any of the component objects from changing.

Here's an example demonstrating the difference:

```js
const obj1 = {
  foo: "bar"
}

const obj2 = {
  key: "value"
}

// Here, obj1 is the same after the Object.assign call
console.log(Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2));
console.log(obj1)
console.log(obj2)

console.log("\n\n")

// Note that after this call, obj1 holds both keys. So this will mutate it:
console.log(Object.assign(obj1, obj2));
console.log(obj1) // This is different now
console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass an empty object in, the original `todo` object will be modified. This may be what you want, but more often than not it isn't.

This is due to the way objects are all references, and are not cloned by default.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Objects and Arrays are assignment by reference.

In this example, changing one will change the other, they are not immutable:

```
let x = {param:1}

const foo = (a) => {
  a.param +=1;
  console.log('response', x, a)
}
foo(x);
```

To fix that, we use Object.assign()

```
let x = {param:1}

const foo = (a) => {
  let b = Object.assign({}, a);
  b.param +=1;
  console.log('response', b, x)
}
foo(x);
```